# Who would a female (pureblood) Sith bond with?

Tags: star-wars, sith, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

Do Sith even marry or have a sense of love? Since they are taking strength from their emotions, I would find it hard to believe that love would be not a matter within a Sith.

But which type of character or person would a Sith bond with? Would it be appropriate to marry an Imperial officer or even a common soldier?

I am asking because I am playing *Star Wars: The Old Republic* at the moment and there are several romance options, so I'm try to decide what to do.

Comment: The point of those games is to do what *you* would want to do, not necessarily what would be in canon.

Comment: @phantom42 And what I want to do is to do what is canon :P. On the other hand, it just made me thinking in general, so I came here to ask. I apologize if that offends you.

Comment: The point of **being a Sith in canon** is to do whatever you want to do. Being a Sith is about freedom. *Cite: Sidious explanation to Darth Maul as a child*.

Comment: If the goal is offspring, they take whoever would make the best pairing. If it's pleasure, they take whoever they want as a lover. If it's love, they take who they love. Being Sith means doing what you want to do, and having the strength to remove any obstacle in your way.

Answer (score 11):

Typically, Sith would marry/breed with the pure goal of powerful offspring.

As [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage) explains, while Darth Malgus took a [freed Twi'lek slave](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eleena_Daru) as his wife, most marriages or unions were with powerful Force users.

> Darth Malgus took a Twi'lek, Eleena Daru, to be his wife, which was considered to be unusual amongst the Sith. This move echoed the past history of the Sith, where members of the Sith species would interbreed with the Exiles. These unions produced many powerful Sith Lords who were strong in the power of the dark side. Marka Ragnos and Naga Sadow were two examples of such beings. Another exotic example of cross-species mating would be the Force-sensitive assassin, Aurra Sing, being the offspring of a human mother and a father of an unknown species, whom she had inherited certain traits from, most easily seen from her pale, alabaster white skin.

[The Exiles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Exiles) mentioned were Dark Jedi who had been banished and were the perfect fitting mates for Sith towards the goal of creating more powerful Force users.

Comment: And, I thought only Vulcans were logical.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**From the book: Lost Tribe of the Sith-Book 1-The Collected Stories**

**During the reign of Naga Sadow Yaru Korsin marries a woman, Seelah (Devore Korsin’s woman before he dies at the hand of his brother Yaru)**

**Excerpt:** “What had happened to Ravilan’s people was partially due to Korsin’s failure at managing that, though he didn’t mind the result. Unlike his wife, he had nothing against the crimson-skinned Sith, but factions threatened order. A homogeneous Sith people was easier to rule.

His wife. Marrying Seelah had been another nod to stability, a bridge between Omen’s crew and its mining-team passengers. There she was, across the dais, greeting the dignitaries the Keshiri were allowed to have. Greeting, that is, without actually touching any of them. Korsin never touched her anymore, either. It was a shame: she was gorgeous now, auburn hair cascading in ringlets around flawless dusky skin. He didn’t know what dark sorceries her team of experts had wrought, but she looked scarcely a day over thirty-five”

**But these are marriages for power and posturing as denoted by the reading of Yaru’s will by his daughter to his wife**

**Excerpt:** “I came here because we just had the reading of Father’s final testament,” she said. It existed—in her care. “He commends his legacy to me—and the three surviving High Lords have ratified it. So you see? You are the mother of the new Grand Lord. Congratulations.” Nida beamed. At her age, she could expect to rule Kesh for decades to come. “Or until the Sith come to rescue us.

Seelah sneered. “You are a child.” She slid from the slab, only to brace herself against it with her hands when her feet failed to respond. “No one’s coming for us. Your father knew that.”

“He told me. It doesn’t really matter to me, one way or the other.”

“It should,” Seelah said, struggling to straighten. “If I tell those people out there …”

Nida casually replaced the cup and stepped back toward the doorway. “There’s no one out there,” she said. “Perhaps you should hear the rest of Father’s final wishes. Henceforth, on the death of the Grand Lord, that person’s spouse and household laborers would be sacrificed. He got the idea from an old Keshiri custom. Technically, it’s to honor the Grand Lord—but you and I know what it’s really about.” She ran her gloved fingers through her hair. “I imagine it’s going to put a crimp in my social life, but I’ll cope.”

Seelah caught her breath. “You can’t mean to …?

**They will most often marry other Sith (Force-User) to produce Force wielding offsprings**

Answer (score -2):

Im playing SWTOR also.

From the game perspective it is YOU that decide what is apropriate and what is not.

So go for the hottest looking, i know that i do!! GO GO Kira Casron!!

If you are really into the character and love roleplaying then consider this:

Pure Sithblood race are a bit touchy about intermingeling and "diluting" the bloodlines as you see in the begining if you play in the Imp side.

But whatever class you play as ( other than Jedi Knight female ) you wont get a chance to romance another Fellow pureblood.

With that beeing the case go for the NeXT best thing witch is marry a force sensitive over a "blunt".