# Can Twi'leks and Sith (purebloods) interbreed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

According to Wookieepedia, Twi'leks and humans can interbreed, although given the popularity of Twi'lek women galaxy-wide and the fact it's not overflowing with such hybrids by now, I'd tend to think the chances of conception were slim. Maybe you would have to be at least a latent Force sensitive, or something?

Anyway, Sith needed their alchemy to breed with humans. I'd think they'd need the alchemy for Twi'leks as well, but no solid evidence comes to mind.

Could Sith and Twi'leks interbreed at all, and if so then what are likely methods?

Examples welcome!

POSTER EDIT: Sith purebloods being the species (except then after a point they were all human hybrids to a degree, eventually interbreeding themselves to extinction into human populations apparently... So either iteration as long as we're talking red skin, facial tentacles, etc. NOT the dark side Jedi equivalents)
Interbreeding meaning offspring were produced. I'm sure an inventive individual could find a way to have a wild night with just about anyone... Or anything... In theory... BUT I SPECIFICALLY ASK CAN THEY MAKE KIDS. *bleaches brain* breeding in biological terms! I was asking because I was making a Sith/twi'lek/zabrak hybrid OC and then realized I had no idea if that was even possible in strict canon, or in the expanded universe.
So, the question was posted
Strict Canon or Expanded Universe only!

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid#cite_note-12

Comment: Sith and humans can interbreed. Humans and Twi'leks can interbreed. It seems likely that Sith and Twi'leks can also interbreed.

Comment: I'm a bit leery of examples being provided... I've been on the Internet before.

Comment: Legends canon: [Darth Malgus took Eleena Daru as a mate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49654/5184). They didn't have any offspring, but they were lovers.

Comment: @Richard that doesn't mean anything... [ring species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species) have the same problem...

Comment: @Armin - Hence why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Sith need alchemy to breed with humans?! Eh? Most Sith (that we see/hear of in the Lucas/Disney films, at any rate) _are_ humans, surely? Anakin was well underway on his path to Sithdom when Padme got pregnant.

Comment: @phantom42 Darth Malgus was a human member of the Sith order. The OP is asking if the species of Sith can interbreed with Twi'leks not not just members of the order that are of different species.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Sith" refers to multiple things - a race (red skin, distinctive facial structure), a government (during the Old Republic era), _and_ a force sensitive order. In the context of this question, they're talking about the race.

Comment: @T.J.L. Ohhh, I see. I didn't even know there was a race. \*hangs head in geek-shame\*

Comment: ...so, nobody has concrete evidence? ...yeah I get it maybe a sith-human hybrid and a twi'lek or twi'lek-human hybrid could... Plausibility... Hmm... Argh but no examples huh?

Comment: Well I guess that's all the answer I'm getting huh? Lol thanks folks, case... Closed?

Comment: In both fan-fic and the force anything is possible. If you want a sith/twi'lek/zabrak hybrid, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't know.**

You are correct that Sith and humans can breed. Sorzus Syn says as much in her segment of *The Book of Sith*.

> After much experimentation, I have concluded that [the Siths'] blood is sufficiently similar to our own to permit alchemical crossbreeding. I know Dreypa, for one, has had his eye on a Sith priestess. He will be pleased to learn his bloodline will not only persist but thrive!

We also know that humans and Twi'leks are quite capable of reproducing without assistance of the Force. For example, [Jek Lawquane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jek_Lawquane).

However, no Sith/Twi'lek hybrids are known to have existed at any point in galactic history, but at no point does anyone state such a union would be impossible. Additionally, given the near limitless possibilities of Sith alchemy, such a creature would seem entirely possible, at least in an RPG or fan-fiction setting where a single author has more complete  control over the universe.

Answer (score -1):

Final verdict, see comments on question: plausibly yes, possibly. Humans can breed with Sith, Twi'lek can breed with humans, it's not a guaranteed 'yes' but still quite likely. Basically what I figured was probably the case, I was hoping there was an obscure example of a hybrid character somewhere but lore hunting it myself... No results.
Thanks everyone! I can now say that my oc could, maybe, perhaps, arise without tumbling lore and history around like jello cubes! One Marty Stu trait killed, hazzah!:3
Again, thanks!
Source:
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid

Comment: I know this is your question, but if you post an answer you should post one that cites sources. It's okay for a question to remain unanswered.

Comment: Yeah, just add one source and people won't feel compelled to downvote.

Comment: Source added, thanks :)